# understanding chart stack generation randomly

Tags: math, d3.js, charts

I'm tring to understand the below logic.

```
function bumps(m) {
    var values = [],
    i,
    j,
    w,
    x,
    y,
    z;
    for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        values[i] = 0.1 + 0.1 * Math.random();
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        x = 1 / (0.1 + Math.random());
        y = 2 * Math.random() - 0.5;
        z = 10 / (0.1 + Math.random());
        for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            w = (i / m - y) * z;
            values[i] += x * Math.exp(-w * w);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        values[i] = Math.max(0, values[i]);
    }
    return values;
}
```

The above code is snippet from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967 and the above function is used to display the random series stack on the y axis in the graph displayed url. I'm trying to understand what they are trying to do in the below

```
x = 1 / (0.1 + Math.random());
y = 2 * Math.random() - 0.5;
z = 10 / (0.1 + Math.random());
```

How to interpret or understand mathematically / logically the above operations in bumps method ? Please help me in understanding the same.

Comment: Can you describe its effect? That would help with seeing the idea of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is JAVASCRIPT which I do not use so I might be wrong but:

```
Math.random();
```

Should return pseudo-random value in interval `<0,1>` so:

```
x = 1 / (0.1 + Math.random());
x = 1 / (0.1 + <0,1>);
x = 1 / <0.1,1.1>;
x = <0.909,10.0>;

y = 2 * Math.random() - 0.5;
y = 2 * <0,1> - 0.5;
y = <0,2> - 0.5;
y = <-0.5,+1.5>;

z = 10 / (0.1 + Math.random());
z = 10 / (0.1 + <0,1>);
z = 10 / <0.1,1.1>;
z = <9.09,100>;
```

So the code just generate pseudo-random variables in specific intervals

```
x = <+0.909,+ 10.0>;
y = <-0.500,+  1.5>;
z = <+9.090,+100.0>;
```